# Zigbee series 2 mesh variable tx power

Tags: zigbee

I am working on a Wireless Sensor Network test bed. I am using a Zigbee Series 2 (2mW) from Digi.

So far, I was able to set up the network with 1 coordinator zigbee (C), 2 router zigbees (R1 - R2) and 4 end-device zigbees(E1,E2,E3 & E4) as sensing nodes for various types of variables (temp, humidity, etc..)

So far the network SHOULD be set up this way. (R1) and (R2) are in the range of (C). Both are in the range of each other at well. However, (E1) and (E2) are only in the range of (R1) and the same applies for (E3) and (E4) on the range of (R2) only. (Assume True if Zigbee's TX power can be controlled. So it is at its minimal now)

Since all of this is set up in a room, all the ZB modules are in the range of each other, however; I would like to know if there is a possibility from the Xbee library or a Physical layer option to reduce/increase the TX power at will.

The idea from this is to test a multi-hopping protocol, so if (R1) is down and (E1) needs to send, it will increase its TX power gradually, until it is able to reach and join (R2) and route its sensed values through it.

I know this may sound either dumb or complicated. But I would like to know of there is an availability for such a thing.

Comment: I doubt how could you set it up in the same room by adjusting the TX power. You should probably try setting different channels on R1 and R2?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate network outages or do you want your wireless modules to run in low power mode?

Answer (score 1):

Last year I worked on a project with Digi XBEE radios, if you are in API mode (Not AT command mode) I believe you can change any setting that you can from their Firmware/Settings tool XCTU. So this should include RF power.

Keep in mind, the RF power alteration will not help you save much energy if that is what you are going for. With a 2mW XBEE, the current spec is 40mA. The portion of that 40mW that is going to RF power is only a few percent. 
Even if you knock the RF power from 2mW to something like 200uW, that saves you less then 1mA.

That all being said, the XBEE modules do have some sleep and power saving options I recall.